# How to eliminate false success messages when implementing post-redirect-get pattern?

Tags: http, post

When implementing the post-redirect-get pattern in a web application, it is common for the final step in your server code to look something like this (pseudocode):

```
if (postSuccessful) 
{
    redirect("/some-page?success=true")
}
```

That is, the redirect URL has some kind of success parameter in the query string so that you know when to display a nice looking "Your form has been submitted!" message on your page. The problem with this is that the `success=true` persists in the query string when it's only needed to initialize the page. If the user refreshes the page or bookmarks it, they will receive a false success message even though no additional POST has taken place.

Is there an elegant solution to this that doesn't involve using JavaScript to eliminate `success=true` from both the query string and the browser history? This solution works, but definitely adds complexity to a page's load process.

Comment: Can't you just display the success message first, and then redirect to "/some-page"?

Comment: The p/r/g pattern only applies to traditional HTTP POSTs. What you're describing would require it being an AJAX POST and then redirecting on the client using JavaScript.

Comment: So, you are finding a solution without JavaScript?

Comment: Well not necessarily, but in my use case, the POST itself needs to be regular and not AJAX, and the browser history hack I mentioned isn't ideal either. If it uses JavaScript but doesn't involve either of these two solutions, that would be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side technology to implement this feature, without any JavaScript. The stes are listed below:

1. When post is successful, redirect to `/some-page` with current timestamp information:

   ```
   if (postSuccessful) 
   {
       redirect("/some-page?success=true&timestamp=1559859090747")
   }
   ```
2. When server receives `GET /some-page?success=true&timestamp=1559859090747` request, compare the `timestamp` parameter with the current timestamp, check whether it is within the last 3 seconds (or you can change this number according to the network environment).
3. If the `timestamp` parameter is within last 3 seconds, then it means this `GET /some-page?success=true` request is a result of server redirect. If not, then it's more like a result of "user refreshes the page or bookmarks it".
4. In server code that handling `GET /some-page`, render different HTML according to the result of step 3. Display the success message only when current access is a result of server redirect.